# Less colloquial version of "Hook in"

Tags: synonyms

> The commercial online assessment services currently offered by PV installation companies require the input of personal details such as email addresses which **hook in** clients.

"Hook in" seems like a bit of a colloquialism, is there a better term for this? To me, the noun hook in the context of "marketing hook" seems alright, but as a verb it seems rather casual.

I want to convey the idea that once the consumer uses this service and provides any personal information, they are stuck or trapped in a loop and are forced to have additional contact or dealings with the business.

I looked up in a thesaurus and came up with snared or lured, but does anyone have any better suggestions please?

Comment: For any downvotes, a comment on why would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your understanding of "hook in" here isn't really correct. The email addresses don't "**lock in**" or "trap" the clients - they simply provide a mechanism by which the companies can **contact** clients in the first place. In [market-speak](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=marketspeak), "hook in" isn't particularly pejorative (it usually just means *obtain*, as here), but related metaphoric usages (*ensnare, lure, entice,* etc.) are more overtly judgemental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could take some of the colloquialism/market-speak feel out of this by 'refreshing' the angling dead metaphor, making it more explicit:

> PV installation companies offer online assessment services as an attractive bait; inducing the prospect to input personal details such as an email address sets the hook.

Comment: Hi StoneyB, after a day of thought, I do think your rewrite solution is best. "Hook" has connotations of being strung in and stuck to a certain degree but with a chance of escape!

Comment: Yah, I thought of adding a clause about "landing" the prospect or "reeling him in" being a necessary third step, but didn't want to crack the wind of the poor phrase!

Comment: Haha I could make the whole paragraph fishing related with "gutting" "phishing" "netting" "catch" and so forth!

Answer (score 0):

Verb *[co-opt](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-opt#Verb)* sometimes is used in such contexts, in sense “To commandeer, appropriate or take over” or in sense “To absorb or assimilate into an established group”.

If you like *[snare](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snare#Verb)* and *[lure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lure#Verb)*, also consider *[waylay](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waylay)* (“To accost or intercept unexpectedly”) and *[hijack](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hijack)* (“To seize control of some process or resource to achieve a purpose other than its originally intended one”); or a little farther afield, *[indenture](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indenture#Verb)* (“To bind a person under such a contract” [a contract which binds a person to work for another]) and *[press-gang](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/press-gang#Verb)* (“To coerce somebody into doing something that they are reluctant to do”).

Comment: Thanks jwpat, your suggestions are brilliant, but for me still misses that bait and hook analogy feel. I guess avoiding some terms probably ends up sounding more awkward!